# Количество ядер процессора

Tags: .net, многопоточность, проектирование

Имеется задача вычислительного характера. Предположительно программа будет исполнятся на машине с многоядерным процессором (процессорами), количество ядер неизвестно заранее.

Вопрос: стоит ли программно определять количество ядер (к примеру с помощью `System.Environment.ProcessorCount`) и создавать соответствующее количество потоков, в которых и будут производится вычисления, или никакого выигрыша в продуктивности подобным образом получить не удаться?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Стоит. Если система может выполнять одновременно 2 потока, а вы будете запускать, к примеру, 4, то лишние 2 потока не добавят эффективности. Если же система может выполнять больше потоков, чем вы создадите, то вы потеряете в эффективности - вычислительные ресурсы (оставшиеся ядра cpu) будут простаивать.

Если задача распараллеливается - ее нужно распараллеливать настолько, насколько это возможно. Конечно, о здравом смысле тоже не стоит забывать. При увеличении количества потоков рано или поздно будет достигнута та ситуация, когда накладные расходы станут соизмеримыми (или превысят) чистое время вычислений.

Answer (score 5):

Иногда стоит, иногда нет -- это зависит от того, какими библиотеками вы пользуетесь.

Например, [PLINQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460688.aspx) и [TPL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537609.aspx), насколько я знаю, самостоятельно опрашивают количество процессоров и выставляют нужную привязку потоков.

Если же вы по какой-то причине решили выйти на нижний уровень и управлять потоками вручную, вам, конечно, придётся учитывать количество ядер в системе. Учтите, что стратегия по количеству потоков зависит от вашей задачи. Если вы пишете числомолотилку, количество потоков большее чем количество ядер обычно не имеет смысла.

Comment: >> Если вы пишете числомолотилку, количество потоков большее чем количество ядер обычно не имеет смысла.

А в каким случаях имеет смысл? Я что-то сходу и не придумаю.

Comment: Я думаю, что ущерб производительности допустимый, например, при работе с UI. Параметры графических компонентов часто необходимо обновлять, даже жертвуя скоростью работы программы. Хотя Я могу ошибаться, ведь с многопоточностью почти не знаком.

Comment: @Flammable: например, каждый поток ожидает чтения файла и обрабатывает его. Да и вообще, любой случай, где bottleneck -- не ресурсы процессора.

Comment: >> Я думаю, что ущерб производительности допустимый, например, при работе с UI. Параметры графических компонентов часто необходимо обновлять, даже жертвуя скоростью работы программы

Я недавно как раз об этом постил. Накладные расходы, связанные с отображением прогресса, можно свести к практически нулевым.

@VladD, данные поступают на обработку по сети, N потоков их читает и обрабатывает по мере получения. Зачем тут лишние потоки?

Comment: @Flammable: а где вы видите лишние? N -- это у вас, конечно, число ожидаемых потоков данных, а не ядер, правильно?

Comment: Подразумеваю, что количество потоков N равно количеству ядер.

Comment: @Flammable, иногда алгоритм  упрощается при связывании практически независимых потоков (процессов) с источниками-приемниками данных. И часто такое распараллеливание существенно систему не грузит, и IO распараллеливается естественным образом, и программировать удобней.

 В таком случае даже не надо смотреть сколько у нас ядер. 

Многие задачи вообще хорошо ложатся на распределенную систему (кластер) и SAN/NAS с практически линейной масштабируемостью.

Comment: >> иногда алгоритм упрощается при связывании практически независимых потоков (процессов) с источниками-приемниками данных. И часто такое распараллеливание существенно систему не грузит, и IO распараллеливается естественным образом, и программировать удобней.

В таких случаях - да, соглашусь.

Comment: @avp: да, я именно это и имел в виду, спасибо!

Answer (score 3):

Зависит от задачи. Вернее, от того, насколько эта задача имеет способность параллелиться. Ну и, само-собой - от Вас: на сколько Вы готовы заниматься планированием этой задачи на ядрах.

Зачастую, существует больше попутных препятствий, чем преимуществ, которые сводят на нет попытки грамотно спланировать задачу на всех ядрах одновременно.

В первую очередь - это **память**, которая, как правило требуется для сохранения результатов. Не всегда ее можно расчитать сразу, приходится задачу делить на 2: расчет ресурсов и решение самой задачи. У меня есть только одна успешная реализация, когда эти 2 задачи получилось решать параллельно на одном пуле потоков без дополнительных издержек. Даже не спрашивайте, сколько времени ушло на ее планирование - много.

Во вторую очередь - равномерное распределение **нагрузки** на все ядра. Вы же не думаете, что просто разделив задачу на n частей, Вы получите увеличение производительности в n раз. Вы можете не получить даже удвоения производительности, если не подумаете об этом шаге.

**Синхронизация** частичных результатов: если Вы распределяете нагрузку, значит у Вас есть масса частичных результатов, которые нужно либо где-то хранить, либо куда-то сливать. Это еще одно узкое место такой реализации.

Ну и синхронизация с пользователем, естественно. Это целая эпопея.

Вот если Вы готовы к такой "неожиданной" прибавке забот - вперед!