# Почему в этом фрагменте кода параллельная секция медленнее последовательной?

Tags: openmp, c++

Написал простейшую программку для демонстрации ускорения с использованием OpenMP:

```
#include <cstdio>

#include <omp.h>

int main()
{
    const long N = 500000;
    float * A, * B;

    A = new float[N];
    B = new float[N];

    double point1 = omp_get_wtime();

    for(int i=0;i<N;i++)
    {
        A[i] = i;
    }

    double point2 = omp_get_wtime();

    #pragma omp parallel for
    for(int i=0;i<N;i++)
    {
        B[i] = i;
    }

    double point3 = omp_get_wtime();

    printf("%f %f\n", A[N-1], B[N-1]);
    printf("Single: %f\n", point2 - point1);
    printf("OpenMP: %f\n", point3 - point2);

    delete[] A;
    delete[] B;

    return 0;
}
```

На Windows 7, собранная VisualStudio она стабильно выдает время работы параллельной секции на порядок большее чем последовательной. В Убунте же оно переменно: бывают значения как большие времени последовательной секции, так и меньшие.

В чем проблема?

Comment: Увеличьте N на 2 порядка.

Answer (score 1):

> На Windows 7, собранная VisualStudio она стабильно выдает время работы параллельной секции на порядок большее чем последовательной. В Убунте же оно переменно: бывают значения как большие времени последовательной секции, так и меньшие.
>
> В чем проблема?

Я уже [отвечал](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/182489#182538), не все так просто. Универсальных средств распараллеливания, которые дадут вам `100%` результат нет. Тут все индивидуально.

У меня есть 3 варианта:

1. У Вас не чистый эксперимент: Вы меряете параллельный расчет **со всеми издержками** на распараллеливании (создание потоков OpenMP, распределение ресурсов планировщика и т.п.).

   Попробуйте провести **серию** экспериментов: заверните их в цикл из 100-200 подходов и посчитайте среднее время. Наверняка, максимальное время будет только при первом проходе.

   Издержки на создании потоков поможет устранить предварительный расчетам холостой вход в секцию `parallel`:

   ```
   long Cores = 0;
   ...
   #pragma omp parallel
   {
     #pragma omp atomic
       ++Cores;
   }
   ...
   //  расчеты
   ...
   printf("cores: %i\r\n", Cores );
   ...
   ```
2. Можно поиграть с параметрами и типом планировщика потоков: [schedule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenMP#Scheduling_clauses)
3. Можно еще проверить [установку маски соответствия процессоров](http://blog.sjinks.pro/c-cpp/517-openmp-setting-cpu-affinity-mask-in-linux/)

Comment: плюс к ответу, и в добавок: что-то лучше поддается распараллеливанию, а что-то хуже. вот более "чистый" [пример][1]. да и не забудь: [Отсутствие openmp][2]


  [2]: http://www.viva64.com/ru/a/0054/#ID0ERG


  [1]: http://pastebin.com/URxC39Z1